# How to display the language name in English from the language code?

Tags: java, scala

I am using the following code, but that returns the name of the language in that language, while I want to display the language name in English.

```
var loc = new java.util.Locale(code)
return loc.getDisplayLanguage(loc)
```

So, how can I return the name of the language in English?

Comment: Have you tried: `var locA = new java.util.Locale(codeA);
var locB = new java.util.Locale(codeB);
return locA.getDisplayLanguage(locB)`?

Comment: Ex: var inEnglish = Locale.CHINESE.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: So why didn't you specify that you wanted the language name in English? What did you think the argument was for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Locale.getDisplayLanguage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage()) displays the language in the default locale. To force it to display in English, you can use [`Locale.getDisplayLanguage(Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage(java.util.Locale)):

```
return loc.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`loc.getDisplayLanguage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage--) returns the name in the default locale, not in the locale of `loc`:

> If possible, the name returned will be localized for the default DISPLAY locale.

So, since my default locale is US English, I will get the following:

```
Locale.GERMANY.getDisplayLanguage() // returns "German"
```

To control the language of the display string, specify the locale using [`loc.getDisplayLanguage(Locale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage-java.util.Locale-). Examples:

```
Locale.US.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);      // English
Locale.US.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);       // Englisch
Locale.US.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN);      // inglese
Locale.US.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);       // anglais

Locale.GERMANY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH); // German
Locale.GERMANY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);  // Deutsch
Locale.GERMANY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN); // tedesco
Locale.GERMANY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);  // allemand

Locale.ITALY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);   // Italian
Locale.ITALY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);    // Italienisch
Locale.ITALY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN);   // italiano
Locale.ITALY.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);    // italien

Locale.FRANCE.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);  // French
Locale.FRANCE.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);   // Französisch
Locale.FRANCE.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.ITALIAN);  // francese
Locale.FRANCE.getDisplayLanguage(Locale.FRENCH);   // français
```